# Gitlab integration with Azure dev ops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, azure-pipelines

I want to use my onPremise GitLab with Azure DevOps pipeline following instructions "How to use GitLab in Azure DevOps".  But I have an issue with connection because of company Firewall.

To open this I need an IP address from the Azure end. 
Please help me here how can I get static IP for AzuredevOps.

Comment: Hey, Could you share the link where you find the instruction for 'how to use gitlab in azure devops'. That would be helpfull.

Comment: @Lumy, did you get that link , because me too am looking for a way of integrating gitlab and azure

Comment: This https://about.gitlab.com/devops-tools/azure_devops/ or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.gitlab-integration I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Hi! I know it's been two years but I'm wondering if you ever managed to make this work?